# How to Replace List of Values in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, list

The below code returns `-infinity` and I'm going to replace that with 0 using `repplaceAll` in Google Earth Engine but it does not work.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6a00596a7c80740c44276068b5f7a0f0

```
var para  = ee.List([0,0,0,40,50,100,200,2, 6, 0, 0 , 10]);

var a = ee.Number(1.728);
var b = ee.Number(1525.9);

var value = para.map(function(x){
  return a.multiply(ee.Number(x).log()).add(b);
});

print('value estimated:',value.replaceAll('-Infinity',0));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to produce a value equal to -Infinity in GEE, but you can use this as a workaround:

```
print('value estimated:', value.replaceAll(ee.Number(0).log(), 0))
```